# Ho to copy text from one file to another in C?

Tags: c, io

I am writing a basic program to copy text to another text file. But in the console window after entering the filename from where text should be taken, the program ends and does not go further. How can I solve this problem?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    char filename1, filename2;
    FILE *infile;
    FILE *outfile;
    printf("Enter a data file name:");
    scanf("%s", filename1);
    infile = fopen("filename1", "r");
    printf("Enter a input file name:");
    scanf("%s", filename2);
    
    outfile = fopen("filename2", "w");
    if (infile == NULL || outfile == NULL) {
        printf("Problem in opening files");
        exit(0);
    }
    printf("files opened successfully");
    char characters;
    do {
        characters = getc(infile);
        fprintf(outfile,"%s", characters);
        printf("%s", characters);
    } while (!feof(infile));
    fclose(infile);
    fclose(outfile);
    return 0;
}
```

[image: windows cmd window showing program run]

Comment: `filename1` is a `char`, not a `char` array or a pointer to the first `char` of allocated memory. Moreover, you are using `%s` to print `char`s - `fprintf(outfile,"%s",characters)`. This is UB.

Comment: when compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.  ( for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11` ) Note: other compilers use different options to produce the same results.  Note: a single char variable like `filename` cannot be used as a target for a `scanf()` that uses `%s` for the input format conversion specifier.  Suggest `char filename[30];` or similar

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of issues.

```
char filename1, filename2;
```

This only allows `filename1` and `filename2` to hold a **single** char - not a C string. You need to reserve memory as a char array. Like:

```
char filename1[64], filename2[64];  // Allow 63 chars for file name
```

Then

```
scanf("%s",filename1);
```

is really bad as it allows the user to overflow your input buffers. Consider using `fgets` or at least do:

```
scanf("%63s",filename1);  // Limit user input to 63 chars as the buffer is 64
                          // The "last" char is for the string termination
```

Then the loop:

First, `characters` shall be `int` so that you can check for `EOF`. Further, check directly on `getc` instead of using `feof`. And don't use `%s` for printing a single char to the output file - use `%c`. Like

```
int characters;
while(1) {
    characters=getc(infile);
    if (characters == EOF) break;      // Break (aka jump out of the loop) on
                                       // end-of-file or errors

    fprintf(outfile,"%c",characters);  // %c instead of %s
                                       // or use: putc(characters, outfile)
                                       // instead of fprintf
    printf("%s",characters);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few problems with your program:

1. You are using `char` variables to hold names of files. These variables should be `char` arrays or pointers to the first `char` of some allocated memory.
2. `fopen("filename2", "w")` seems wrong. Although, the first argument should be a `char *`, you are not reading / writing the files you just asked the user to enter.
3. `fprintf(outfile,"%s",characters)` - You are using `%s` to print characters. This will invoke [UB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).
4. `char characters` - The last character of a file, the `EOF` character is guaranteed to fit in an `int`. The `characters` variable should be declared as an `int` so that it can hold the `EOF` character.

Here is the program that works:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 

int main(void) {

        char filename1[10], filename2[10];
        FILE *infile;
        FILE *outfile;

        printf("Enter a data file name:");
        scanf("%s",filename1);
        infile  = fopen(filename1, "r");

        printf("Enter a input file name:");
        scanf("%s",filename2);
        outfile = fopen(filename2, "w");

        if (infile==NULL || outfile==NULL) {
                printf("Problem in opening files");
                exit(0);
        }

        printf("files opened successfully");
        int characters;
        /*do {
          characters=getc(infile);
          fprintf(outfile,"%s",characters);
          printf("%s",characters);
          } while(!feof(infile));
          */
        while ((characters = getc(infile)) != EOF) {
                fprintf(outfile, "%c", characters);
                printf("%c", characters);
        }

        fclose(infile);
        fclose(outfile);
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Consider using `if (scanf("%9s", filename1) != 1) return 1;` to prevent undefined behavior on invalid input, `putc(characters, outfile)` and `putchar(characters)` for symmetry with `getc()` and for efficiency too.

Comment: @chqrlie Thanks for pointing these out. I will just be lazy about this and let the OP include your suggestions in their program.